# Fatou's Lemma or some convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence, limsup-and-liminf

I would like to phrase properly the following result.

Let $f(x,\mathbf{y})$ be some bounded and continuous function for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,...,y_k)^T\in\mathbb{R}^k$ is a vector of variables, such that there exist a function $w(x)$ such that $\frac{f(x,\mathbf{y})}{w(x)}$ is bounded for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} \frac{f(x,\mathbf{y})}{w(x)}=\psi(\mathbf{y})$. Now consider the expression
\begin{eqnarray*}
h(\mathbf{y}) & = &\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{f(x,\mathbf{y})\phi(\mathbf{y})}{\int_{\mathbf{Y}}f(x,\mathbf{y})\phi(\mathbf{y})d\mathbf{y}}=\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\frac{\frac{f(x,\mathbf{y})}{w(x)}\phi(\mathbf{y})}{\int_{\mathbf{Y}}\frac{f(x,\mathbf{y})}{w(x)}\phi(\mathbf{y})d\mathbf{y}}=\frac{\psi(\mathbf{y})\phi(\mathbf{y})}{\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\int_{\mathbf{Y}}\frac{f(x,\mathbf{y})}{w(x)}\phi(\mathbf{y})d\mathbf{y}}\\
& = & \frac{\psi(\mathbf{y})\phi(\mathbf{y})}{\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\int_{Y_1}...\int_{Y_k}\frac{f(x,(y_1,...,y_k))}{w(x)}\phi(\mathbf{y})dy_k...dy_1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that we have $k$ integrals and $Y_1,...,Y_k$ are the support of $y_1,...,y_k$, respectively, hence ${\mathbf Y}={\mathbf Y_1}\times...\times{\mathbf Y_k}$. I don't know whether this is relevant, but the integration of limits of each $y_i$ ($i=1,..,k$) varies, that is, some are $(-\infty,\infty)$, others $(0,\infty)$.

From this point, which convergence theorem shall I use to pass the limit inside the integral? I thought of Fatou's Lemma (and reserve Fatou's Lemma) to find the same lower and upper bounds for the integral, but I am sure which conditions (?) I must impose to $\phi(\mathbf{y})$ to apply Fatou's Lemma. Clearly, $\psi$ must be $\phi$-integrable, but is that it?. According to the assumptions, which convergence theorem would be better to apply? In summary, I would to formalize this result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please rewrite the denominator so that it's obvious where $y$ --- the argument of $h$ --- appears and where the dummy variable of integration appears

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have added some more details. $\mathbf{y}$ will appear only in the numerator, since we are integrating it out in the denominator. Actually, thinking of $h(\mathbf{y})$, the denominator will be a constant. I hope to have answered your suggestions. thanks.

Comment: Is $\phi(\mathbf y)$ integrable? If so, the usual dominated convergence theorem applies since $|(f/w)\phi|\le C|\phi|$

Comment: Yes, $\phi(\mathbf y)$ is integrable, but my concern is the multiple integral (with different limits of integration), is that enough to assure the result?